# No spiders found on ScrapeOps Platform

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm new in ScrapeOps platform.
I have already used scrapy to run some websites. All the scripts are fine by running one-by-one in my machine.
To automatically schedule my spiders, I'm trying to deploy ScrapeOps on my server.
I successfully connected my GCP server (ubuntu 22.04) and clone the repository from GitHub by following the guidance on ScrapeOps.
However, there is no spider found.
I tried to find tutorials, but nobody talks about this miss-capturing issue.
I think the ScrapeOps renew the ways to deploy, so there might be different between now and last year.

Here is some pictures for ScrapeOps platforms and terminal log.
[Servers & Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2AIV.png)

It's weird that it shows 'Spider discovered' as I clicked the button 'Find Scrapy Spiders', but it stills no spiders found at all.
[Servers & Deployment > Cloned Repos: Credit_All_In_One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZao0.png)

And the command below seems to work fine:

```
scrapy list
```

[The command scrapy list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raln9.png)

Here is the my scrapy.cfg:

```
[settings]
default = credit_card_scraper.settings
shell = ipython

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = credit_card_scraper
```

And Here is my GitHub structure (I have 24 spiders, but just takes 2 spiders to show the structure):

```
Credit_All_In_One
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapy.cfg
└── credit_card_scraper
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── database.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── american.py
        ├── cathay.py
        ├── ...
```

Please help me to fix the problem...
Very appreciated!